# Question the solution: a question

Tags: rebus

```
                  against ^
                  against |               v--- this
is  +  busbus  +  against | . gnra  +  >,  , @
```

The solution to this rebus is a question. You do not have to answer it, just discover it. Good luck, and happy puzzling.

### Hints

> 1. The top against is the final against.
> 1.2. An action is being displayed in the against.
> 1.3. It is *not* being stacked.
> 2. Google `gnra` with some other words to find its true meaning.
> 2.2. i.e. other words in the puzzle. (Assuming you have part of the puzzle already solved.)
> 2.3. `gnra` is a misspelling and shortening of an English word.
> 3. Some programming knowledge might help.
> 3.2. `.`.
> 4. The rebus is self-contained.
> 5. [The band](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/riseagainst/thestrengthtogoon.html)
> 6. The answer is yes, apparently.

Comment: This may take a while...

Comment: I do not understand upvotes before the solution is found. How do people know this is a good puzzle?

Comment: @Gendarme If it's hard to solve, then it's probably a good puzzle.

Comment: @Gendarme you can upvote it if it's an (seemingly) interesting puzzle. More people will read it and reward the poster for the effort. If it turns out to be a bad puzzle, it's easy to change your vote.

Comment: @Raystafarian - except that you can't change your vote unless the post gets edited...

Comment: @Alconja Doesn't that only apply to down-votes?

Comment: @Alconja then edit it yourself. And Khale - no.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ can we get a hint since it hasn't been solved for a week? Looking over the comments and answers, the last part has stumped everyone.

Comment: @Gendarme A puzzle can be *intriguing* even if you don't know the answer yet. It can look *interesting* and make you *want to tackle it*. All reasons I would use to upvote before seeing a solution.

Comment: The last part `>,  , `. Is that Brainf**k?

Comment: @ABcDexter No, it is not. But such a program wouldn't do much ;)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Ok, and is that `v--- this` placed above there on purpose, right? The exact placement of characters/symbols in a rebus is important O:-)

Comment: @ABcDexter Yes, indeed!

Comment: Any hints? Or anything? I ended up awarding my bounty to the best answer, but it seems like no one has made any progress

Comment: Ping! This one is still not completely solved. Any other hint(s) to help wrap it up, @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ?

Comment: @DanRussell The final hint is all you really should need... but okay.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ But [Wesley's answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/31237/21234) below is still not quite right?

Comment: @DanRussell bother, I didn't know he updated. Regardless, he is only slightly wrong.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Looks like Wesley updated again...did he nail it?

Comment: @DanRussell Close enough!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's an updated attempt with the new hints.

is

> is

<strike>bus</strike>*bus*

> *this* (@paste) rebus

against ^ 
against | 
against |

> Rise Against (the band)

.

> . as a member/property access operator --> possessive --> 's

gnra

> **general** no longer makes sense in the context of the band, so perhaps gnra is a misspelling of **genre**

>, , @

> **?** from ASCII
>  `>` is 0x3E
>  `?` is 0x3F
>  `@` is 0x40
>
>  From @DanRussell, interpret this as **question**

Following @Neon612's connection

> Rise Against's genre would be **hardcore**

Answer

> Is this rebus a hardcore question?

Comment: `.` is an operator, but what else does it mean? And true, the question _wouldn't_ make much sense unless gnra meant something else... ;)

Comment: It could also be accessing a property, so perhaps `.` translates to possessive, transforming "a question" to "a question's". But I'll have to see what gnra could mean to see if it works. :p

Comment: But what about operator precedence?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that since I thought `.` would take precedence over most other operators, unless concatenation by `+` takes precedence here... Then, if `>, , @` translates to `?` using ASCII, and if googling "gnra question" is supposed to lead to "Did you mean: **general** question", maybe the entire phrase would then be "stacked against a question's misspelled(?) general question"

Comment: you're getting close, but `.` isn't concatenation in all languages.

Comment: Oh, sorry I meant `.` as accessing a property in my last comment.

Comment: I feel like this has to be the closest anyone's gotten so far. But obviously I don't know the answer so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: i would interpret the italics in the second part to mean *this* so maybe prefix that word with "this"?

Comment: I awarded you the bounty because the time period ran out and this is as solid an answer (and well-defended!) as I've seen,

Comment: Close enough. I was going for `hard` question, but this works.

Answer (score 14):

Possibility for the last part:

> The character that comes between > and @ in ASCII is ?.  So that would simply be a question mark.

Answer (score 10):

Anyone have any thoughts? It looks to me as if the second element is

> Rebus (because it is bus crossed out and re-inserted)

The third could be

> Up against  or Going up against or Rising up against or Stacked up against
>  On the other hand that could be an arrow pointing to the title
>  gnra = Tetraloop = four-loop or for-loop --- or "general"

The last suggests

> Nothing left over or  possibly
>  Left over space

Comment: You close on the second one, and you're right on the first one if I understand correctly.

Comment: GNRA can refer to a tetraloop, which makes me wonder if the `.` means to concatenate whatever's found with the 3 against+up statements with it, somehow.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha are you thinking about GRNA? or GNRA?

Comment: [GNRA](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1370402/)

Comment: The last part looks a lot like Befunge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge

Comment: At first I thought "gnra" could mean something like "the odds in general", as in "the odd-numbered letters in the word", but that would have been "gnrl". There doesn't seem to be any feasible word of which "gnra" are the odd-numbered letters, though.

Comment: Some other potential interpretations of "gnra":  [Glasgow North Regeneration Agency](http://tinyurl.com/jl87l98), [Grand National Racing Association](http://tinyurl.com/gulvdwe), or the previously-mentioned [Gateway National Recreation Area](https://www.nps.gov/gate).

Answer (score 9):

This is a potentially incendiary answer, and I needed to mix things up a bit to get it, but...

> Is Stack against mixing up the rebus repetition behind the Top Question list's lack of content?

Explanation:

> 'Mixing up' came from needing to rearrange the clues.  'is' is is, <strike>bus</strike>bus is 'rebus' as guessed by Hugh Meyers, the againsts are 'Stack against', the arrow points to 'question' in the title, or the 'Top Question', GNRA is a Tetraloop, which becomes 4 loop and for loop as guessed by Khale_Kitha in the comments, which finally becomes 'repetition'.  The final clue is a list missing one of the pieces, or 'list's lack of content'.  'Behind' is because 'rebus' was before (or behind) 'repetition' in the original clue order.

I think I'm stretching this too far, but you guys come up with really complex puzzles, so I actually don't know.

Comment: `'is' is is`... hehe. Had to read it a few times to convince myself it was legit.

Answer (score 6):

I'll take another crack at it:

is

> is

busbus

> rebus

against ^
against |
against |

> Rise Against (the band)

.

> . as a member/property access operator (@Wesley Situ)

gnra

> shortening and misspelling of **genre**

Putting "against, ., gnra" together

> It would come out "Rise Against".genre = **hardcore**

">, , @"

> ? (@WestleySitu)

Answer

> Is this rebus hard?    (For an answer to this question, a resounding YES!)

Comment: Nice thoughts! Not quite right, though.

Comment: I think the . before gnra is important too

Answer (score 5):

The arrow could also be pointing to the word "question" (e.g., this question), and between the commas could just be "space". So far I'm getting

> Is this rebus against Stack's question...

Comment: This is an answer, so you should use spoilers to hide stuff

Comment: You're rather close on some parts.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Added another interpretation. Is that better?

Comment: @stackErr no closer than you were ;)

Answer (score 3):

> How is the rebus stacking up against the general questions

My thought process

> 1. Against's are stacked up. So "stack up against". Credit to everyone who guessed it
>  2. Googling "gnra question" leads to google suggesting "general question". Credit to Wesley Situ
>  3. The "." (as I have seen in C++) is used to reference structure. Thank you Wesley Situ for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

Second attempt:

The stack of *against*s all the way to gnra is interpreted as a block:

> stack of against = rising against (clue 5).
>  up-arrow = question.
>  gnra = general (clue 2.3).
>  dot: a.b = property b of a => question.general = general question
>  Altogether: rising against general questions

Tying this with elements from my previous attempt, we get:

> Is rebus rising against general questions?

---

First attempt:

I think the rebus reads as:

> Are rebuses up against themselves often?

Here are the elements:

Is

> Is

<s>bus</s>*bus*

> rebus

3-stack of 'against's, last one at the top

> up against itself

Up arrow points to

> n

Dot

> structure's property: $a.b$ means property $b$ of structure $a$. So the dot reverses the elements around it and inserts "of" in between. We'll deal with gnra later, but "n." becomes "of n", or **often**.

gnra (using the [community wiki](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/30452/9422) started by Hugh Myers)

> tetraloop $\to$ for-loop $\to$ multiple.

Middle of final triple (using the [community wiki](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/31221/9422) started by ffao)

> ?

Putting it together:

> Is rebus up against itself multiple often?

Or, taking 'multiple' as an operator on the previous word,

> Is rebus up against itselfs often?

Now making this more grammatically correct:

> Are rebuses up against themselves often?

As a bonus, it satisfies the title's 'answer in question' recursive property.

Comment: I think it's the closest to the correct answer(if anyone has written it yet) :-)

Comment: Thanks @ABcDexter! Clue 5 has thrown a spanner in the works, since it just about states that the pile of *against*s together with the up-arrow is something like "rise against". I also wonder about the lack of "+" symbols up to gnra. This may indicate a single word or symbol.

Comment: Yes exactly, and I mentioned in my answer, that `.` is causing hallucinations.(exaggerating a bit).

Answer (score 2):

Going from charfellow's answer, if the solution is somehow related to Stack Exchange, then perhaps the last bit could be

> up-vote this

Comment: I certainly wouldn't mind that, haha. Not quite the answer I was looking for, however.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

> Is (this) rebus (a) true or false general question?

Explanation:

> is = **is**

> <strike>bus</strike>bus = **rebus**

> `|` and `^` are bitwise operators in programming languages.
>  Where `|` is an "bitwise inclusive OR" and `^` a "bitwise XOR (eXclusive OR)" (both with the same *operator precedence* <- order of execution)
>
>  Using the hint: *The top against is the final against.*
>  We know the order of the operators: `| | ^`
>  In addition, a dot (the **`.`** is sometimes used as `x` in math.
>  Using a comment from OP: *But what about operator precedence?*
>  The full order is: `| | ^ x`
>
>  Against is a synonym of *opposite*, so I think the (bitwise) values are altering. Either:
>  `0 | 1 | 0 ^ 1 x 0`
>  OR
>  `1 | 0 | 1 ^ 0 x 1`
>
>  Since I don't knew whether to start with `0` or `1`, I tried both:
>  `0 | 1 | 0 ^ 1 x 0` = 0
>  `1 | 0 | 1 ^ 0 x 1` = 1
>
>  Then, umm.. I decided to translate it to **true or false**. :)

> `gnra` = **general**

> `>,  , @` with the arrow pointing between it is the `?` (question mark) in ASCII order. So this part is **question?**.
>  Thanks to [@ffao](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/31221/13190) for this part.

And the answer to the question is:

> true, since it's a true or false question.
>
>  or false, because if you google "*true or false general question*" you'll receive hits for "*true or false general **knowledge** questions*".
>  And I don't think this rebus or question is general knowledge imho, although this is debatable.

Answer (score 1):

The first part could be

> Is rebus stacked against

The portion after the up arrow (if indeed that is an arrow) could be

> gnra = tetra-loop = four-loop = for loop.
>  Then, the portion with the commas could be referring
>  how a for loop is written such as in `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`.
>  The middle portion is being pointed to, and is the *condition* for 
>  the loop. Of course, this fails to properly account for the '<'
>  appearing as the first entry and the existence of '@' at all. 
>  The arrow points to the question (as has been noted), so perhaps
>  that is the best translation.

Putting this together gives

> Is (this) rebus stacked against the question's conditions?

Comment: Close, but not quite.

Answer (score 0):

So after working upon everyone's comments and answers, here is my answer:

> Is `rebus` stacking against or for, to upvote this question ?

The really confusing part shifted from `>, ,@` to `. gnra`, as taking `.` as member access  meant there has to be a stackexchange member named `gnra` but with wasting-cum-investing time on search, there is none.

I just hope this (awkward) answer is somewhere close to the correct one, will be working more on to update it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be very close to the intended answer. If not, I hope someone else can do a better translation from the inputs. :/

> Is this rebus stacked/ up against each question having greater upvotes than this question? **OR**
>  Is rebus on stack (stack overflow) against each question having greater upvotes than this question?

Explanation:

> 1. The busbus with a strike through = rebus
>  2. The stacked against is relatively straightforward 
>  3. The arrow points to the "question" in the title 
>  3. As mentioned in the community wiki post, **gnra** is tetra loop which can be translated to "four loop", which gives for loop. For loop when combined with the **.** symbol gives- **.forEach**, which is a method to traverse through an array in [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
>  4. **>** is the symbol for greater than.
>  5. The last element translates to "upvotes @ this"

Answer (score 0):

After reading the hints, I think it is:

> Is this rebus rising against its general property?

Explanation:

> "Is" is is. (As @Vicky poetically said it)
>
>  <s>bus</s>*bus* is rebus
>
>  According to the hint (band): the against's + arrow turns into rising against
>
>  `.` operator in programming languages allows your to access an objects properties. This added with the abbreviation of gnra for general becomes "its general property"
>
>  The missing element in the last part is the `?` in ASCII (thanks to @ffao)
>
>  Adding it up all together you get:  **Is this rebus rising against its general property?**

Good question but I don't have a good answer to it!

> Rebuses general property is to use pictures to represent words but in this rebus (if you want to call it that) its using words/text to represent words.